# How do I recover my desktop settings after accidentally changing my home directory?

Tags: home-directory, settings

I'm new to ubuntu.I'm using ubuntu 11.10.

Today I execute `usermod -d /etc/skel USERNAME; chown -R USERNAME /etc/skel` command by login root user. After a reboot It had changed my home folter path to /etc/skel. Also I had lost my desktop settings too. Can any one let me know how to recover this.

Answer (score 2):

Do this

**usermod -d /home/your_home_directory USERNAME**

**chown -R USERNAME /home/your_home_directory**
This will recover your settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your home directory is set up from `/etc/passwd` file. Being the root user, you can edit this file to set the home directory. Be sure to relogin afterwards.